# Class level variables Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to angular I have a class level variable in my angular component called moratoriumID. I call a method which calls a POST and then assigns a number to moratoriumID that is returned from the POST . I believe this works as intended, as I see the number show up in the chrome debugger console . Later on I try to access the variable and use it. It says its undefined. Why ? What am I not understanding ? How can I use the moratoriumID later in code ? Any explanation would be most appreciated.  --Jason

```
export class AddMoratoriumsComponent implements OnInit {
   moratoriumID: number;

   //this gets called and assigns the moratoriumID from what I see
   PostMoratorium(moratoriumtopost: Moratorium):void {    
     this.moratoriumService.PostMoratorium(moratoriumtopost)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe((data) => (this.moratoriumID) = (data),
    (error) => (console.log(error)),
    () => console.log('Post moratorium is complete', this.moratoriumID), 
  );}

    //...I call it
      this.PostMoratorium(moratoriumtopost);

    //Later I try to use moratoriumID but it says its undefined ...why ?
       if (this.selectzipvalues.length>0){
         const res = this.isoLocs.filter(i => this.selectzipvalues.includes(i.zipCode));
         res.forEach(myFunction);
         function myFunction(item) {
            const moratoriumlocationstopost = {
              county:item.county ,
              city:item.city,
              zip:item.zipCode,
              moratoriumId:this.moratoriumID, //IT SAYS ITS UNDEFINED ..WHY ?
    } as MoratoriumLocation;
```

}}

Comment: ```Post``` is concurrent. The rest of the code keeps running before the requests completes. If you want them to run sequentially you need to move all that code inside ```subscribe``` or either leverage composition or call backs. And please move all this code inside ```ngOnInit``` it is extremely hard to control concurrent effects without hooking them to the life cycle properly

Comment: Again, new to angular not sure what "leverage composition" or "callbacks" really means. I read somewhere to use concatMap(). Not sure though. I guess if I coud get an example it would be helpful. - Jason

Answer (score 0):

Answer seems to be be to use switchMap().